# UIViewController memory management

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller

Hi I have a very basic issue of memory management with my UIViewController (or any other object that I create);
The problem is that in Instruments my Object allocation graph is always rising even though I am calling release on then assigning them nil.

I have 2 UIViewController sub-classes each initializing with a NIB;
I add the first ViewController to the main window like `[window addSubView:first.view];`
Then in my first ViewController nib file I have a Button which loads the second ViewController like :

```
-(IBAction)loadSecondView{
     if(second!=nil){ //second is set as an iVar and @property (nonatomic, retain)ViewController2* second; 
         [second release];
         second=nil;
     }
     second=[[ViewController2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
     [self.view addSubView:second.view];

}
```

In my (second) ViewController2 i have a button with an action method

```
-(IBAction) removeSecond{

    [self.view removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Please let me know if the above scheme works in a managed way for memory...?
In Instruments It does not show release of any allocation and keeps the bar status graph keeps on rising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why use this scheme when second is a property:

```
if(second!=nil){
     [second release];
     second=nil;
 }
 second=[[ViewController2* second]initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
```

A propery automatically releases it's old value when the setter is used. So this could be rewritten as:

```
if(self.second == nil) { //Prevents creating a new controller if there already is one.
     self.second = [[[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil] autorelease];
}
```

Also, what's up with `[ViewController2* second]`?
Why is that asterisk there, and what does the class method `second` do?

Comment: sorry that was just an alloc call....i miss typed it....

thanks for the advice... correct me if i m wrong but what i have understood from ur theory is that If i go on allocing the iVAr set as a property, it will release the previous allocation by itself ?

Comment: Yes, a property will always (afaik) release it's previous value when the setter is invoked. When you define the property as `(retain)`, it will release the old object, and retain the new object.

Beware though: when doing this: `self.someStringProperty = [[NSString alloc] init]`, the property will retain the new value, so you have a retain count of two. `self.someStringProperty = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease]` will prevent this.

Comment: ok i tried your suggestion but 
if(self.second != nil) { //Prevents creating a new controller if there already is one.
     self.second = [[[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil] autorelease];
}
never gets called so i changed the if condition to if(self.second==nil)
which works but then again my graph in Object Allocations is still rising.

Comment: This is what i did in my (first) ViewController1 button action method



-(IBAction) loadSecond{

 if(second==nil)
  self.second=[[[ViewController2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil]autorelease]; 
 
 
 [self.view addSubview:second.view];


}

Comment: @Rengers: What do you mean by `retain)ViewController2* sceond`?

Comment: @jAmi: Yes, sorry it should be `if(self.second==nil)`. I fixed it in the post. Are you sure you are deallocating the view controller?
---  
@KennyTM: How the hell did that get there? Some copy paste error I guess. Shouldn't be there. Removed it in the post.